# Calculating percentiles in pandas

Tags: pandas

new to python and am learning as I go along. I mainly work from pandas dataframes.

I have a consumer survey and I want to break it into groups based on income percentile. So bottom 10th, 10th-20th etc. And I'd want to create a seperate column describing which %ile each agent lies in.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
from string import ascii_letters    
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Agent=pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list(ascii_letters), (100, 5))).sum(1),
        Salary=np.random.randint(50000, 150000, (100))
    ))

df['Salary Decile'] = pd.qcut(df.Salary, 10, labels=list(map('D{}'.format, range(10))))
```

---

```
df

    Agent  Salary Salary Decile
0   TLuIY  110708            D5
1   ZaxpV  111411            D5
2   TGaTY  116893            D6
3   SitLP  133517            D8
4   hsFWf   54198            D0
5   LLiUV  146248            D9
6   npFCo  113458            D6
7   JfeMa   56040            D0
8   jqkOA   91098            D3
9   BEZKe  144488            D9
10  QyoUG   72309            D2
11  azYaB   83156            D2
12  qpXxz   57682            D0
13  cEvNV   64950            D1
14  QRalI  122120            D7
15  SifWk  103399            D5
16  qBMOy  130008            D8
17  agTRX   54760            D0
18  ZCFyB   97051            D4
19  bBhzc   69204            D1
20  bhgXT   96809            D4
21  pFWNQ  126710            D7
22  EXLyx  122152            D7
23  HaSdg  137614            D9
24  uGtKH   59155            D1
25  Dkbqq   84346            D2
26  nsxMp  101822            D5
27  lppEj  114105            D6
28  nQQez   78923            D2
29  UOzZa  113714            D6
..    ...     ...           ...
70  wCQDZ  102920            D5
71  nYEfT  140140            D9
72  FDXdG   99796            D4
73  CPCHY  111255            D5
74  SxXfK   91946            D3
75  BGwnC  135886            D8
76  gNLkt  115078            D6
77  VsNhX   77128            D2
78  oJZFB  117714            D6
79  ERqEy  123873            D7
80  SWNPP   86705            D3
81  LOXQU  147105            D9
82  dEfhH   76160            D2
83  OlDLD   61954            D1
84  chzAB  132647            D8
85  cOdBf  111554            D5
86  ekqMa   84482            D2
87  VYELR   92139            D3
88  iTNsN   51796            D0
89  QTOtk  111048            D5
90  mzuDF  100903            D4
91  fSJjS   97345            D4
92  zjMUt  127831            D7
93  NRXjs   83754            D2
94  YxnIu   90778            D3
95  FiIbR  123566            D7
96  CpUsf   97854            D4
97  SCren  130119            D8
98  oBLpq   60390            D1
99  WgELS  122030            D7

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```